# Type of prices in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price

We can get from a product a few different prices, like:

```
$product->getFinalPrice();
$product->getCalculatedFinalPrice();
$product->getPrice();
...
```

How many types does Magento 2 have and what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have Price, Final Price, Special Price, Tier Price, Group wise Price.

You can see price related functions are here

**vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php**

```
getBasePrice - Get base price with apply Group, Tier, Special prises
getChildFinalPrice
getFinalPrice - getFinalPrice
getExistingPrices - Gets the 'tear_price' array from the product
getTierPrice - Get product tier price by qty
getTierPrices - Gets list of product tier prices
```

**vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product.php**

```
getCalculatedFinalPrice - Not sure. May be not much used.
```

For more info

http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-special-price-configuration-tutorial/

http://magetips.com/price-types-in-magento-and-how-the-price-rules-work.html/